# How can I search input words in a collection of word sequences using mongoDb

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm relatively new to mongodb and, so far, I've got nowhere near a solution to a problem I've solved previously with an SQL backend.

The problem itself is very simple: I've got a large number of ordered word sequences of arbitrary length kept in a database, something like:

```
Sequence #0: [ "word1", "word34", "word56", …, "word_66" ]
Sequence #1: [ "word45", "word2", "word334", "word45", …, "word_668" ] 
...
```

In the database sequences, the same word might appear more than once.

Given an input word sequence like ["word2", "word334"], I'd like to retrieve all the database sequences which contain the input words in the same order they are given.  The only particularity is this: there can be one word (at maximum) allowed between the words of the input.  So, for example, the sequence ["a", "a", "b", "c"] would be a match for the input ["a", "c"], "b" being a "skipped word" in that case.  Let's assume that all the sequences were already written in the database using whatever data model prior to any search being performed; only the query is of interest.

With SQL, this problem is easy enough to solve with a single query into normalized tables. But I'd like to solve the same problem using mongoDb.

First, I tried replicating the tables in mongoDb exactly as I had them in SQL. I figured I'd adapt the queries in the mongo query language as I went.  That didn't work so well, because I found no way of comparing two documents from the same collection within the same find()-- (that was a naive attempt at emulating some kind of JOIN).

Next, I tried grouping the sequence words in an array, in a "sequence" document and making sure all the necessary info was available in the same document.  Using the aggregate() pipeline, I tried to see if I could not get away with "chaining" a few $match stages.  The best I could do in the $match stage was to filter the sequences that had all the input words in them (using $all), but I could go no further because I could never find the mongoDb way to express "compare the position of one word in the document's array to the position of another word in the same document's array" (apparently, you can't put a field on the right hand side of a query comparison operator, even from the same document).

Then I though I could get away with coding a javascript function computing the solution for one document and calling it within a $where stage following the $match. I wasn't successful with this approach either, because I couldn't find a way to pass my input sequence (an array variable) to the $where clause.  I even tried to compose by hand the query string based on the input, so that it contained only resolved constants to run it afterward, but to no avail (apparently, $where doesn't like passing local variables as params, and doesn't like array constants).  I tried uploading the functions to the server, just in case, but I had no luck with that either, restrictions seem to be more or less the same.

At that point, the only thing I can see that could work would be to put all the sequence words in one big string, and use a $regex operator that would perform the match.  That would be a bit ugly, because of the possible "skipped word", and very slow because of regex and also because no index could ever be used in that case. I didn't try the full-fledged mapReduce pipeline, but at first glance it seems just like an expansion of the aggregate() and so probably equally unsuited to solve this problem.

I've gone through the documentation a couple times and didn't discover any other "special feature" or notion that could help me.  Could someone knowledgeable in MongoDB modelling nudge me toward some efficient approach?  What could be a mongoDb-friendly data model for this? I'm not looking for code as much as some design outline relevant to this specific problem. Thx.

Comment: While I'm not sure that you couldn't have gotten the inefficient $where to work, honestly, this doesn't sound like a good fit for MongoDB. As you've seen, it's design and usage is quite different from a traditional SQL database, and thus, not all queries can be mapped to it's query capabilities.

Comment: Does the `$all` approach not filter the results down to a sufficiently small set that a client-side scan for the ordering-constraint-with-one-skipped becomes sufficiently fast?

Comment: Is there a limit to the input sequence? i.e. if it was just 2 you could compute and store all possible sequences of length 2 for a given record and store those on the record allowing a direct index to find the result.  Or if it is >2 would indexing the first two in this was give sufficient specificity to allow a scan of those results?

Comment: Yet another approach would be to store all suffixes in the array (i.e. for A, B, C you would store "A B C" and "B C".  Now your regex can be rooted and queries can be fully resolved using the index (which should be in RAM and therefore very fast).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There are no limit to the input sequence.  Can the $all benefit from indexes? I'll try your suggestion and compare with the solution I've created to see which one is faster on a large set.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, although I'm not sure how optimal is my solution (I'll make some automated tests to ascertain how fast/scalable it is).

Because mongoDb isn't able to compare two separate documents together in the same query (probably to make sure queries can be parallelized), it's hard to resort only to its query "language" to compute any kind of connectivity property.  In my case, my structure amounts to a simplistic DAG.  So, instead of storing the individual nodes (words) of the sequence with an index indicating its position (and let the query language infer connectivity through interval checking of the indices as in SQL), I use the edges as the basic document, that is: word_i (start node) connected to word_j (end node). To this edge document, I add the sequence id, as well as ordering info. To create the database collection, since I can skip one word between matches, I need to add two edges at most for every start word.  I also added all the index so that the $sort and $match stages can take advantage of them.

Given the input sequence, I first use the aggregator with several stages:

Stage 1: When I want to search for an input sequence (for example: ["word_a", "word_b", "word_c"]), I start by rounding up ($match) all the database edges matching those inferred by the input sequence, in this case : ("word_a"->"word_b") and ("word_b"->"word_c").  Of course, this will retrieve false positives because I can't express that the "word_b" is to be the same exact instance in both edges whenever there's a match, and I can't ensure that the same edge won't match twice in the sequence while the other edge doesn't match at all, and I also will get sequence with too few matches.

Stage 2: I $sort the result by sequence id and start word index.

Stage 3: I $group the previous results by sequence _id.  The sort in stage 2 puts the edges in order of appearance in the sequence.  At the same time, I $addToSet all start nodes in a set, and end nodes in another set.  I also $sum the number of matching edges in each group.

Stage 4: I $match to remove all the groups that don't contain enough edges to match the input (this takes care of removing the sequences that contained not all the edges I wanted).

Stages 5,6,7,8: My next goal is to make sure that all the words I want are accounted for, so I count the number of elements in each of the sets computed in stage 3 ($unwind the set, followed by a $group with a $sum : 1 in a count field).

Stage 9: I $match to keep only the edges that have the same word sets cardinality as the same ones derived from the input sequence.  (This accomplishes more or less the same goal as the "$all" of my first failed attempt at a solution).

Stage 10: I $project to summarize all the fields for the next step.

The only thing I have not been able to compute within the aggregator is the connectivity between edges: I don't know if the end node from an edge matches the start node of the following edge.  But because the set of matching sequences is now reduced to a minimum and all edges are sorted in order of appearance in the sequence, I can do a quick pass in Javascript to keep only the sequences where the desired edges appear in succession (modulated by the word skip tolerance constraint).  I would have tried to cram all of it in the aggregator, but unfortunately $where doesn't seem to work in there.

In any case, this seems fast enough and the speed seems quite constant regardless of the input length (on a randomly generated sample db), and the time spent in javascript is negligible.  As expected, the edge table grows quite a lot but with mongo, this shouldn't be a problem I hope.  I also can't easily change the word skip constraint value (to 2, for example) of course, because this require modification to the main collection.

Conclusion: Although there might be faster and better solution, through this work I familiarized myself a bit more with mongoDb.  I hope the mongo team will eventually beef-up their "one-document evaluation language set" to cover other handy operators that don't break their parallel model, like $size for arrays, $removeFromSet, having fields on right-hand side of operators, test on array values, more arithmetic operators like $sqrt, etc...